# C# populating dataTable in Visual Studio 2015 from table in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a program in Visual Studio 2015 that is pulling data from a table in MySQL. I am new to SQL so I may be going about this the wrong way all together. What I need is to basically mimic the table from MySQL into a C# application. I have created a new dataset called DataSet4 and within that it has a table called DataTable1. This table has 2 columns, ID and Name. Right now my code (shown below) only pulls the first row from the table. How would I add a foreach loop to this to pull all rows from mySQL? I hope I stated this clearly enough, if not I will do what I can to try and explain. There is a lot more to it than this but I feel like I can figure it out from there. I did try just setting up a dataset that pulls the table directly but that kept freezing my Visual Studio.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cnC03.Open();
            s = "SELECT * FROM c03.tbl_kit t;";
            mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, cnC03);
            mdr = mcd.ExecuteReader();


            if (mdr.Read())
            {
                DataRow newDataRow = dataSet4.Tables["DataTable1"].NewRow();
                newDataRow["ID"] = mdr.GetString("ID");
                newDataRow["Name"] = mdr.GetString("Name");

                dataSet4.Tables["DataTable1"].Rows.Add(newDataRow);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            mdr.Close();
            cnC03.Close();
        }
    }
```

New code:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            s = "SELECT ID, Name FROM c03.tbl_kit";
            using (cnC03)
            using (MySqlCommand mcd2 = new MySqlCommand(s, cnC03))
            {
                cnC03.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader mdr = mcd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("DataTable1");
                    dt.Load(mdr);
                    dataSet4.Tables.Add(dt);


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fill-Populate-DataTable-using-MySqlDataAdapter-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: How many rows are you expecting? Also, wrap your resources in a `using` block

Comment: I will be doing this for multiple tables. this table for instance only has 3 rows, but other tables have 20,000 plus rows. Not familiar with the using block.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load all data returned by your query in a DataTable then you could shorten your code a lot with

```
s = "SELECT ID, Name FROM c03.tbl_kit";
mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, cnC03);
mdr = mcd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(mdr);
```

See MSDN on [DataTable.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note that if you need only two fields then you should add the exact column's names required in output to the query text.

In your code I see a potential problem. You don't have a local variable for the MySqlConnection. This poses a big problem because a connection is a disposable object and should be created, used and disposed as soon as possible.

I would write something like this

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        s = "SELECT ID, Name FROM c03.tbl_kit";
        using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
        using(MySqlCommand mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, cnn))
        {
            cnC03.Open();
            using(MySqlDataReader mdr = mcd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("DataTable1");
                dt.Load(mdr);            
                //.... use your table ....
                //.... or add it to the global dataset
                //.... of course this means that you haven't done it manually before
                dataSet4.Tables.Add(dt);


            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: I changed my try code to the below but it still only gave me 1 row.
try
    {
        cnC03.Open();    
        s = "SELECT * FROM c03.tbl_kit t;";    
        mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, cnC03);    
        mdr = mcd.ExecuteReader();    
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
        dt.Load(mdr);    
    }

Comment: sorry couldn't figure out how to space it out.

Comment: DataTable.Load(...) loads everything that is returned by the MySqlDataReader. If you have just one row then the query returns one row. (Code in comments cannot be formatted correctly)

Comment: Steve gave you the using blocks. Also, limit your queries with a `where` clause or `LIMIT x,y` for pagination. You can't just go loading all the rows up in some cases.

Comment: when I run "SELECT * FROM c03.tbl_kit t;" on the table in MySQL it pulls 3 rows,

Comment: I know. I am talking general situations that you must be wary of. Afterall, it could blow things up. Like an enjoyable UX.

Comment: How do you check the number of rows returned and added to the datatable? After the dt.Load try to add a MessageBox printing the dt.Rows.Count value

Comment: `dt.Rows.Count` or `dt.DataRows.Count` or some jazz like that. Not uncommon and often smart to do a get scalar call for "select count(*) from tblXYZ where this and that" first.

Comment: @Steve I guess it has been too long since I have used C# because now I am even more lost than I was before and nothing is populating when I click the button. I am updating my original code to show what I have. I have already set cnC03 as a connection string earlier in the program and it seems to work since it will at least pull the first row.

Comment: Do not use the cnC03 but create a new connection using the connectionstring. Then use that connection in the MySqlCommand constructor

Comment: Did you have used a _MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count)_ after the _dt.Load(mdr);_ ? If yes what value do you get?